# How to remove 00 in timezone moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I want to remove the 00 when its 1:00 PM
value i have,

`startTime = '1:00 PM'  ||  '2:30 PM'` 
`endTime   = '10:30 PM' ||  '2:30 PM'`

`eg :  1:00 PM - 2:00 PM  --> output(1 PM - 2 PM) // need to remove 00 in this case`  
`eg :  1:30 PM - 2 PM   --> output(1:30 PM - 2 PM) // remove 00 from second time` 
`eg :  1:40 PM  - 2:30 PM --> output(1:40 PM - 2:30 PM) // nothing remove`

Comment: What does this have to do with timezone? Why not just `replace(':00','')`?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I'll resolve it:

```
var momentDate = moment('<your date>');

function removeMinutes(momentDate) {
   var momentTime = momentDate.format('LT'); // Time formatted as 10:00 AM
   return time.replace(/(:00)/g, '');
}
```

So, for example

```
var momentDate = moment('2021-04-29 10:00'); // Moment Object
var formattedTime = removeMinutes(momentDate); // '10 AM'
```

Hopefully this can help you.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the minute is zero before you format it:

```js
const time1 = moment('14:00:00', 'hh:mm');
const time2 = moment('14:30:00', 'hh:mm');

const format = time => {
  if (time.minute() == 0) return time.format('h A');
  else return time.format('h:mm A');
}

console.log(format(time1))
console.log(format(time2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: i dont have entire date i just have time only

Comment: @MehulJariwala If you only have the time, you simply need to tell Moment what format to expect. See my edited answer.

Comment: @MehulJariwala What do you mean, it outputs "1:00 PM"? In my browser, running that code snippet outputs "2 PM" with my example time.

Comment: input ->> "1:00 PM"

Comment: output -->> "1 PM"

Comment: @MehulJariwala Isn't that... what you're asking for?? `1:00 PM` to turn into `1 PM`?? And if you don't have your time in 24 hrs, don't give it to Moment in 24 hrs... Moment will parse it properly either way. You just have to describe the format you're giving it to it in. Mine is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that also takes [i18n](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) and the localized formats into account. Since different locales have different formats, one can't simply look for the colon `:` character, for example:

```
moment('2023-08-30 14:00:00').locale('en').format('LT') // '2:00 PM'
moment('2023-08-30 14:00:00').locale('sv').format('LT') // '14:00'
moment('2023-08-30 14:00:00').locale('fi').format('LT') // '14.00'
moment('2023-08-30 14:00:00').locale('br').format('LT') // '2e00 PM'
```

So you could do something like:

```
const timeWithoutMinutes = (date) => date.format('LT').replace(/(\d{1,2})[^\d]00\b/,'$1');

timeWithoutMinutes(moment('2023-08-30 14:00:00').locale('en')) // '2 PM'
timeWithoutMinutes(moment('2023-08-30 14:00:00').locale('sv')) // '14'
timeWithoutMinutes(moment('2023-08-30 14:00:00').locale('fi')) // '14'
timeWithoutMinutes(moment('2023-08-30 14:00:00').locale('br')) // '2 PM'
```

Answer (score -2):

Pretty simple

```js
let op = moment(11.00).format("HH")

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the 2nd part even if the input value is 11:30?

Comment: sure ! but it is issue with timezone. For workaround we have to moment-timezone